# JUnit Thread Testing

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, junit

I have client and server threads in my applications. When I run these apps as standalone apps, these threads communicate properly.

But when I run client as JUnit and server as standalone, client thread dies within few seconds.

I couldn't get, why such different behavior.

Comment: Do you get any exception when the thread dies?

Comment: No Exceptions... :(
And the weird thing is the same thing work as standalone app

Comment: How exactly does the thread "die"? How do you know?

Comment: I am running this in Eclipse. And after a second or two I get JUnit run successful and I can see process end on eclipse console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the JUnit runner terminates, all spawned threads etc. are killed too (as it is most likely run in a separate JVM instance).

Here is a (rather old) [article describing the problem you experienced](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/08/06/multithreadedTests.html) (the GroboUtils library it is recommending seems to have been abandoned long time ago though). And [another, recent one](http://garygregory.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/multi-threaded-unit-testing/), with a more modern solution using the new Java concurrency framework.

The gist of the latter solution is that it runs the threads via an executor, which publishes the results of the runs via `Future`s. And `Future.get` is blocking until the thread finishes with the task, automatically keeping the JUnit tests alive. You may be able to adapt this trick to your case.

Comment: Yeah I am guessing the Same but How can I achieve the thing that I wanted then ? 
Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Hey Peter, Ur exactly right. runner thread terminated all the spawn threads. I have just put sleep of 50 seconds in a test block and I got rest of the responses as well :) 
Thanks :)